# Materialised view migration erroring, using knex

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have an SQL query that my company mentor wrote that creates a table with columns voucher_Id, `quantity`, `used` and `remaining`, however, he was showing me an example of what I need in my postgres database and wrote it inside of the query tool. I have made some small amendments however when I try to create the Materialized View via a migration the following query throws an error:

Here is his query he wrote in the query tool on postgres which works like a charm:

```
SELECT v.voucher_id,v.quantity, COUNT(ov.voucher_id) AS "used", v.quantity - COUNT(ov.voucher_id) AS "remaining"
      FROM public.vouchers v
      LEFT OUTER JOIN public.order_vouchers ov ON (v.voucher_id = ov.voucher_id)
      GROUP BY v.voucher_id, v.quantity
```

And then in my migration using knex I have:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_vouchers
    SELECT * FROM vouchers,
      SELECT v.voucher_id,v.quantity, COUNT(ov.voucher_id) AS "used", v.quantity - COUNT(ov.voucher_id) AS "left"
      FROM public.vouchers v
      LEFT OUTER JOIN public.order_vouchers ov ON (v.voucher_id = ov.voucher_id)
      GROUP BY v.voucher_id, v.quantity
```

The error is thrown specifically near `SELECT`, the tables I am using are `vouchers` and `order_id` .I am very new to this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `SELECT` clauses.  Is this what you want?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_vouchers as
      SELECT v.voucher_id, v.quantity, COUNT(ov.voucher_id) AS "used", v.quantity - COUNT(ov.voucher_id) AS "left"
      FROM public.vouchers v LEFT OUTER JOIN
           public.order_vouchers ov
           ON v.voucher_id = ov.voucher_id
      GROUP BY v.voucher_id, v.quantity;
```

Comment: Ah, I was pondering how the migration will get all of the `vouchers` table data without using `SELECT * FROM vouchers`, I assumed that the postgres query tool had some automatic scope over all of the table data while the migration didn't. I shall try it now.